# Google Analytics: Unable to use a custom dimension as a secondary dimension in reports

Tags: google-analytics

We track search terms (e.g. michael kors handbags) entered on our site as an event (i.e. captured in eventLabel). We have a custom dimension that parse the list of product ids returned on a search page.

Example:
'michael kors handbag' returned 5 products on search page. Custom Dimension 1 parses a list of product ids: '12345, 23456, 34567, 45678, 56789'. On an event report, when I use this custom dimension 1 as a secondary dimension, no data is returned. I am seeing the two tags fired (i.e. one as an event hit and the other as a pageview hit) - I am not able to figure out why the custom dimension 1 cannot be used as a secondary dimension.

Any insight is helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Show your configuration, pls

Answer (score 0):

The dimension needs to be scoped at Session level, so it's available for all the hits within a session.

Probably the dimension is set at hit level, so the information doesn't persist, when you try to relate it to the event, GA cannot do it.